# search do not search for letter "š"

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

NOTE: it works on phpMyAdmin
also works if i do this in country query `LIKE '%"Šveice"%'`

I have search bar in my website .If I try to find word "Šveice" (Šveice in Latvian = "Switzerland" in English) it will not find anything but if I try to search "veice" it will find it.
All other letters are working.

This is what i got :

GET search

```
if (isset($_GET['query'])){
    $query = htmlentities($_GET['query'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
}
```

input

```
 <input type="search" name="query" placeholder="Search..">
```

Using on database

```
varchar(100)    utf8_latvian_ci
```

part of query

```
(address LIKE '%".$query."%' OR country LIKE '%".$query."%')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the function misuse.

If you think of it, a function named **html**entities doesn't seem to be having any relation to the SQL stuff. And it doesn't.

Instead of some irrelevant functions you have to use **SQL-related** operators. Namely prepared statements. So your PHP code should be

```
if (isset($_GET['query'])){
    $query = "%".$_GET['query']."%";
}
```

and SQL like

```
(address LIKE ? OR country LIKE ?)
```

then prepare your query and execute it usual way

Comment: Today i think that best solution is to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

Comment: Stripe my last comment xD now i m using PDO